# Blurry/aliased text on external LCD in Lion

Tags: macos, display, font

I have an external LCD hooked up to my MacBook Pro 5,5 running Lion. I have major aliasing on the external monitor in every application. Using the commonly recommended `defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int x` (with any value 0-4) has no effect on restarting applications or rebooting. The monitor is running at its native resolution, 1440x900, although I had to use SwitchResX to get OS X to recognize this resolution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This could be caused by a number of things, could you tell us how you're connecting to the monitor, such as VGA, DVI, HDMI, and what model the monitor is?

Comment: @AlanJC Sure, sorry. It's VGA to mini DisplayPort, the monitor is a cheap ProView 900W.

Comment: FWIW I'm experiencing similar issues with a Samsung LED display connected via HDMI to my MBP. It's running at 1080i resolution. Text looks terrible on it no matter what.

Comment: Btw. Aliasing and Blur are different things, almost opposites.

Answer (score 1):

As its on a VGA connection, it may not be aliasing or the resolution, but could be the phase of the monitor. It should have settings on he monitor itself to auto configure or manually adjust things like this. Do you have the ability to reset the monitor via an OSD?

Comment: Hmm, no, I don't. I tried adjusting the phase setting on the monitor and it seemed to have no effect at all. I also used the autoconfig function to no avail.